# Having issues with .h file, it doesn't seem to be linking correctly

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am learning C++ through a Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" and the first part of the drill of the chapter is to show the use of .h files. The drill is extremely simple and I followed it to the letter but I keep getting 'undefined reference to foo' when I try to compile. I will write the three files down bellow, they are super short.

by the way, std_lib_facilities.h is a .h file the author included that has a few includes in it like iostream as well as 'using namespace std;' and some functions the authors wrote that you need to use from time to time

my.h - contains extern int foo; void print_foo(); void print(int);

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);

#endif
```

my.cpp - includes my.h, defines print_foo() to print value of foo using cout and print(int i) to print the value of i using cout

```
#include "my.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void print_foo()
{
    cout << foo << '\n';
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout << i << '\n';
}
```

use.cpp - includes my.h defines main() to set the value of foo to 7 and print it using print_foo() and print the value of 99 using print()

```
#include "my.h"

int main()
{
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

The OS I am using for this is Linux if that helps

Comment: What part of "undefined reference to foo" you are not sure about? The error message could not be more clear, and you most certainly haven't defined `foo` anywhere.

Comment: "std_lib_facilities.h" is presumably a file that contains a whole lot of includes and a `using namespace std;`  Stop using it as soon as possible.  Bringing in includes you don't need just slows your compiler down.  And `using namespace std;` can lead to surprises, and is an especially bad idea in a header file since there's no way to reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
extern int foo;
```

`extern` means that somewhere out there is an `int` named  `foo`. But it's not defined here. This is just a declaration of `foo`'s existence, a promise to the compiler that `foo` will exist when it's needed. The compiler will carry on and allow the use of `foo` even  if it doesn't know where `foo` is yet.

This means that in one of the cpp files there must be a

```
int foo;
```

to define `foo` and keep this promise.

[Documentation on on `extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I feel like this a a pretty dumb question I just wasn't sure what was up because the drill practically told you exactly what to do.